# solving error unauthorized /rest-auth/registration/ in django allauth

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

Hello guys I finally can ask for help since I believe my issue is holding me back for the third day now googling. am using react in the frontend and Django in the backed and am trying to register user, the login is working like charm! but when I try creating new user I get error

```
Unauthorized: /rest-auth/registration/
[05/Jun/2019 10:34:45] "POST /rest-auth/registration/ HTTP/1.1" 401 27
```

I am sure that is the path to register user because when I visit the link in the browser it works fine. the issue is I am sending data from react frontend set like this

```
export const authSignUP = (username, email, password1, password2) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authStart);
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/', {
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password1: password1,
            password2: password2
        }).then(res => {
            const token = res.data.key;
            const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate);
            dispatch(authSuccess(token));
            dispatch(checkAuthTimeOut(3600));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            alert(err)
            // dispatch(authFail(err))
        })
    }
}
```

and my django settings file is like this

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


#This is required otherwise it asks for email server
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'jobs_home.serializer.TokenSerializer',
}


ROOT_URLCONF = 'jobs_dj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../build')
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
      'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
      ],
    },
  },
]

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True   
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

#Following is added to enable registration with email instead of username
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
 "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

 # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
 "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

REST_USE_JWT = True

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jobs_dj.wsgi.application'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
  },
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',  'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

I will really use someones help in breaking this wall.. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, so will leave a comment - did you try to manually set authentification class of register view to allow_any?
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: Okey I know probably this is error with the headers but my questing is, the user is not authenticated, where do we get the header a parameters to pass or how do we tell django not to expect any authorization from headers?

Comment: @IgorBelkov  let me try that. thanks. will tell you how it ended up

Comment: I gave you the wrong link, sorry ) Here what I meant by "setting allow any"
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany
Setting permission_classes, not authentification.
The AllowAny permission class will allow unrestricted access, regardless of if the request was authenticated or unauthenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting the authentication class in my REST_FRAMEWORK settings in the settigs.py file was the issue I changed the settings to be

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
}
```

and it finally worked. this came to me whn even listing database objects needed authentication even after setting permissions to allow any. I knew that by default It was tring to authenticate the users even when I did not need it.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent half an hour debugging this so maybe my solution will help someone.

My issue was that the browser had a token still and was sending it on registration (due to working on multiple projects on localhost). I would double check your request headers.